# Is it possible to bind focus event for all the inputs in web app in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, events, global

I have existing web app in Vue. Now I need to create an event for each input/textarea focus. Is it possible to bind it globally so I don't have to add @focus="function" to each element?

Comment: Yes of course .

Comment: Before you post, summarize the problem and provide details and example for that to describe what you’ve tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't it be possible?

- Get required elements
- Assign whatever functionality you want

```js
mounted () {
  // Get all input elements with class="CLASS_NAME"
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.CLASS_NAME')

  // Iterate over elements and add each one of them a `focus` listener
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('focus', this.inputFocusHandler)
  })
},
methods: {
  inputFocusHandler (event) {
    ...    
  }
}
```